# Dynamically create JavaScript source code using Jint in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, json, parsing, jint

I am working on a project where it requires to parse large numbers of .js files and programmatically update JavaScript code and save it to the same location from where it is loaded.

Is this possible to do this using the Jint Engine and JavaScript Parser and could you please how to do this?

For Example, I have many JavaScript files in different folders **scripts.js** with the following lines of code

```
(function () {
    return {
        ready: function () { 
            
            
        },
        destroy: function () { 
            
        },
    }
});
```

I have to convert these files using C# as follows

```
(function () {
    return {
        ready: function () { 
        console.log("scripts.ready called");
            
        },
        destroy: function () { 
            console.log("scripts.destroy called");
        },
    }
});
```

Please help me how to achieve this using Jint in C#. Is there any other library that can be used to dynamically/programmatically create javascript code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask]. StackOverflow is not a service for writing programs for free. Please attempt your project, and if you run into any specific issues come back with the code and ask a question then (after doing some research).